# I have error "Undefined index: host" in when I tried to practice this code in my localhost

Tags: php

I am really new in php. Here is my code:

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$r_domain = substr(['host'], strpos($uri['host'],"."), strlen($uri['host']));

if ( $domain == $r_domain ) {

/*Open the connection to our database use the info from the config file.*/
$link = f_sqlConnect('root', '', 'group_project');
```

Comment: 1) `substr(['host'],...` is a typo; 2) if you parse `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` you obtain only `$uri['path']`

Answer (score 1):

[`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) is intended to parse a string in this form:

```
scheme://host/path?query#fragment
```

So, if you parse this string:

```
https://www.example.com/pages/mypage.php?one=two#wow
```

the result of [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) will be:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => https
    [host] => www.example.com
    [path] => /pages/mypage.php
    [query] => one=two
    [fragment] => wow
)
```

But you parse `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, that is something like ‘localhost’, ‘www.mysite.com’, ‘127.0.0.1’. In other words, a string without a particular significance for [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), because there is not any element to associate it with an URL.

Parsing (i.e.) ‘localhost’ will obtain only this:

```
Array
(
    [path] => localhost
)
```